# Using Postman pm variables in a GraphQL query

Tags: graphql, postman

I have a GraphQL api - in my pre-request script I want to run a query to find the current items this returns.  I can do this.  I then wanted to set that as a postman variable using `pm.variable.set("myterm", value)`. My issue comes with using this in a postman query in the body of the request.  When I use `pm.variables.get("myterm")` I get errors around the GraphQL body containing a "." (at pm.) - I also tried to enclose the whole thing in single {} and double {{}}

Am I using the wrong variables here?

Comment: Pls, add more image or code of what you've done. Not enough info to figure out what's wrong.